# pip install is not working. cannot import name 'Requirement' from 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources' (unknown location)

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm using Mac OS. Python 3.8 was already installed, as pip 20.0.2

But I cannot install any package by $ pip install, because of `ImportError: cannot import name 'Requirement' from 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'` (unknown location)

**ERROR:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! try reinstalling, and consider filing an issue over [the repo](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues) if it persists.

Comment: Also, please post your error message as text, not an image

Comment: Reinstall Python and/or pip.

Answer (score -1):

In windows I have also faced same error and it can be fixed by slight modification in the below file.

change the old hidden import line to new like below just copy below code and add it in hook-pkg_resources.py

Filename = C:/Python38/Lib/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-pkg_resources.py

```
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('pkg_resources._vendor') + ['pkg_resources.py2_warn']
```

Comment: Unfortunately don't have such file: hook-pkg_resources.py
Probably it names different?

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure about the names in mac os